# Calculate the effective refractive index from group index

Tags: optics, refraction, photonics

I'm currently trying to calculate the *effective refractive index* $n_{eff}$ of waveguides using the (measured) *group index* $n_g$ and the wavelength $\lambda$. 
I started with the relation between $n_{eff}$ and $n_g$:

$$n_g = n_{eff}(\lambda) - \lambda\cdot\left (\dfrac{d}{d\lambda} n_{eff}(\lambda)\right) .$$

Here I am stuck - if I know $n_g$ and the wavelength $\lambda$, can I use the above relationship to determine $n_{eff}$, or is there another approach that I should use?

Comment: This sounds like something that should be solved by using a computer program - you can approximate the derivative as something like $\frac{n_{eff}(\lambda+\Delta\lambda)-n_{eff}(\lambda)}{\Delta\lambda}$ and then solve it using computational linear algebra techniques.  (Perhaps do some research to decide what the best way to approximate the derivative is for your specific application)
I'm assuming that this is for a set of experimental measurements?

Comment: So the problem is, I already got $n_g$ and $\lambda$. Starting from this, I was hoping to calculate $n_{eff}$ from $n_g$ (not vice versa), as you would do when solving a ordinary differential equation but got stuck.  $n_{eff}$ is the parameter I want to calculate. As mentioned, I'm not sure if the relation is  even solveable analytically for $n_{eff}$ (I'm not a mathematician...)

Comment: Do you have $n_g$ as a function of $\lambda$ - if so maybe edit the question to include that?

Comment: No, $n_g$ is one of the parameters I already know. $n_g$ is a measured value ($n_g \approx 2$, $\lambda \approx 850$)

Comment: You can't solve a differential equation with one measured value - you have to measure $n_g$ over a range of wavelengths - the whole nature of a differential equation is that one of the parts of it relates to how something varies, and we can't k know how something is changing if we only know it at one point. I have provided an answer that will work if you know more values

Comment: Yes, I see my problem now. That’s helping. Assuming I have multiple values for $n_g$ at different wavelengths (between 850 and 855) (which I indeed have), how do I solve the equation provided? I‘m still a little bit confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133002/discussion-between-fizzkicks-and-agentsmith).

Comment: I just wanted to add the background to equation you're tend to using and other approaches you asked to determine effective index.

$$n_g = n_{eff}(\lambda) - \lambda\cdot\left (\dfrac{d}{d\lambda} n_{eff}(\lambda)\right) .$$

is a form of Sellmeier formula (also called Sellmeier equation Sellmeier dispersion formula, after Wolfgang von Sellmeier)

Comment: There are many other equations that have been used to represent the refraction index of optical materials as a function of wavelength. The earliest is the Cauchy equation, which dates back to 1836.  - https://wp.optics.arizona.edu/jpalmer/wp-content/uploads/sites/65/2017/03/dispeqns.pdf
 - https://www.rp-photonics.com/sellmeier_formula.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can rewrite the differential equation as:
$$\frac{1}{\lambda}\frac{dn_{eff}}{d\lambda}-\frac{n_{eff}}{\lambda^2}=\frac{d}{d\lambda}\left(\frac{n_{eff}}{\lambda}\right)=-\frac{n_g}{\lambda^2}$$

So$$\frac{n_{eff}}{\lambda}=C-\int\frac{n_g}{\lambda^2}d\lambda$$for some constant $C$, which you can establish using suitable boundary conditions.

To solve this using numerical data, as you have suggested in the comments, between $850\space\text{nm}$ and $855\space\text{nm}$, you would replace the integral with a sum:
$$\int\frac{n_g}{\lambda^2}d\lambda\approx\sum\frac{n_g}{\lambda^2}\Delta\lambda$$ where $\Delta\lambda$ is the wavelength spacing between measurements.

Comment: To determine the constant of integration $C$, you should have some condition on $n_{eff}(\lambda)$.

Comment: Thanks, that's helping a lot!